# Vf page and record types

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to assign a record type with a visual force page.

I have this usecase,when i change owner to a particular type of user ,record type is updated.
This record type should be associated with a page layout of minimum information.
As i cannot take standard mandatory fields from a normal page layout,that wont work
In short whenever i see this record,it should have only minimum information and should be associated with this particular minimum page
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the View/Edit links of the object with your custom VF page using the standard controller. In an extension controller you can check the record type of the source record - If it's the one with minimum information, then just render your VF page on which you'll display your desired information, otherwise forward the user to where they came from and append `&nooverride=1` to the url which will redirect the user to the standard page layout associated with the record type.